# Multi panel figure, superimposed labels and vertical alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats, minipage, overlays

I am trying to make a figure with 4 subfigures in a 2x2 array, with A-D labels superimposed on the panels.

I've used `minipage` and `lpic`, but the pictures don't align vertically.

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lpic}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]

{\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{lpic}[draft]{../img/technovit/vasca(0.50,0.50)}
\lbl{10,110; \textbf{A}}
\end{lpic}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{lpic}[draft]{../img/technovit/primoa(0.50,0.50)}
\lbl{10,110; \textbf{B}}
\end{lpic}
\end{minipage}

\par


\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{lpic}[draft]{../img/technovit/meria(0.50,0.50)}
\lbl{10,110; \textbf{C}}
\end{lpic}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{lpic}[draft]{../img/technovit/corea(0.50,0.50)}
\lbl{10,110; \textbf{D}}
\end{lpic}
\end{minipage}
}
\caption{Technovit}
{\small Misc images - scale bars are 200$\mu$m}
\label{Techno}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The figure ends up looking like this:

[image: 4 square panels of blue stained plant sections]

(I used `[draft]` to emphasise the alignment).

How do I make these images align vertically? Why aren't they automatically - they are the same size and share a preamble!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a table, since you're not adding subcaptions.

[image: imagines in a table]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lpic}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
   \begin{lpic}[draft]{example-image-1x1(0.8)}
   \lbl{10,60; \textbf{A}}\end{lpic} &  \begin{lpic}[draft]{example-image-1x1(0.8)}
     \lbl{10,60; \textbf{B}}\end{lpic} \\[4ex]
  \begin{lpic}[draft]{example-image-1x1(0.8)}
  \lbl{10,60; \textbf{C}}\end{lpic} &  \begin{lpic}[draft]{example-image-1x1(0.8)}\lbl{10,60; \textbf{D}}
    \end{lpic} \\[4ex]     
\end{tabular}
\caption{\small Misc images - scale bars are 200$\mu$m}
\label{Techno}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you made is to have `{\centering ...}`, which should be `{\centering ... \par}`. You need to end the paragraph for it to work properly. You may also want to add a `\centering` inside each of the `minipage`s, and possibly add some extra space between the two rows of images, with `\vspace`. (A blank line is the same as a `\par`, so the `\par` you currently have there doesn't do much, by the way.)

I don't have your images of course, so I used `example-image-1x1` instead. The positions of the ABCD labels are wrong, because I haven't adjusted the coordinates for this example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lpic}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
{\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering % added \centering in every minipage
\begin{lpic}[draft]{example-image-1x1(0.8)}
\lbl{10,110; \textbf{A}}
\end{lpic}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{lpic}[draft]{example-image-1x1(0.8)}
\lbl{10,110; \textbf{B}}
\end{lpic}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{6mm}


\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{lpic}[draft]{example-image-1x1(0.8)}
\lbl{10,110; \textbf{C}}
\end{lpic}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{lpic}[draft]{example-image-1x1(0.8)}
\lbl{10,110; \textbf{D}}
\end{lpic}
\end{minipage}\par} % <-- added a \par before the }

\caption{Technovit}
{\small Misc images - scale bars are \SI{200}{\micro\m}}
\label{Techno}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```